# Footer disappears from listview after returning to its tab

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using ViewPager with 3 pages , each holding a listfragment. I place a footer for each listfragment's listview. Now, when I go to 3rd tab and then return to first, the footer is missing and the scroll listener also stops firing. I can get the scroll listener started again by binding the listener in `onActivityCreated`, but since `list.addFooterView` doesn't work after `setListAdapter`, I am not able to put in the footer view again into the listview.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you will only ever have 3 pages in your `ViewPager`, the easiest solution I can think of is to call [`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)). The first fragment will no longer move beyond the offscreen page limit when you visit the third fragment, so it will never be removed from the `ViewPager`.